# Script in Google Sheets to automate Sales Assignments

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am brand new to Stack so if I am asking in the wrong place I am sorry. I have a google sheet with 3 columns.

- Column A sales account ID
- Column B sale Dollar amount
- Column C Sales Rep

The sales rep column is blank until I assign sales reps to those accounts.

I try to do it evenly and fairly by using a countif/sumif function to keep track as I assign accounts so I know how many each rep has and for how much money.

I usually just assign the rep with the lowest dollars the next account in line so the money is even and the number of accounts is even as well.

I was hoping to find a way to automate this process. I wrote a Vlookup that tells me the rep with the MIN amount of dollars based on the sumif function but I can't apply that moving forward because I keep running into circular dependencies in Google sheets.

Even If I allow circular dependencies, a friend who knows this stuff better than me told me since the sales rep that needs the money is always changing I need some coding in the background to do this.

Any ideas or help would be great!

Comment: Welcome. The question is too broad. Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts to write the script that you need.

Comment: If you're going to use google apps script to maintain a script like that you're have to learn to program. Especially if the sheet is subject to change. I'm assuming you're asking this because you don't know what a map data structure is. The second option is to give each sales rep a 'Dollar amount' column and make a row at the top for totals and use the spreadsheet functions to sum the columns.